# wxPython Grid Interfering With Modal Behavior

Tags: python, wxpython

When I display a modal dialog after calling show grid, the user input on the panel is not blocked. Before calling show grid, the modal dialog behaves correctly by blocking any user input on the panel. Am I doing something wrong that would create this behavior? Here is how I setup my classes (Python 2.7, wx 4.0.0a3):

```
Import wx

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, style=(wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE & ~(wx.RESIZE_BORDER|wx.CAPTION)) | wx.FRAME_SHAPED | wx.FRAME_FLOAT_ON_PARENT)
        self.firstPanel = MyFirstPanel.MyFirstPanel(self) 
        self.secondPanel = MySecondPanel.MySecondPanel(self)

class MyFirstPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self)
        self.myTextControl = MyTextCtrl.MyTextCtrl(self, style=wx.WANTS_CHARS|wx.BORDER_NONE)
        self.myButton = MyButton.MyButton(self)
        self.myButton.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.__OnMyButton)

    def __OnMyButton(self):
        self.myDialog = MyDialog.MyDialog(self, style=(wx.DEFAULT_DIALOG_STYLE & (~wx.CAPTION)) & (~wx.CLOSE_BOX) | wx.STAY_ON_TOP | wx.FRAME_SHAPED)
        response = self.myDialog.Query()
        self.myDialog.Destroy()
        event.Skip()

class MySecondPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self)
        self.myGrid = MyGrid.MyGrid(self)

class MyGrid(wx.Grid):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Grid.__init__(self, style=0)
        self.CreateGrid(0, 2)
        self.SetWindowstyle(self.GetWindowStyleFlag()&~wx.HSCROLL)
        self.Layout()

class MyTextCtrl(wx.Control):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Control.__init__(self, style=wx.WANT_CHARS | wx.BORDER_NONE)

class MyDialog(wx.Dialog):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Dialog.__init__(self):

    def Query(self):
        response = self.ShowModal()
        return response

class MyButton(wx.Control):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Control.__init__(self)
```

In this example, if I show the first panel and press the button, the modal dialog blocks all events to the entire panel including events to the text control. If I show the second panel containing the grid object and then return to the first panel and press the button, the modal dialog does not block events.  With the dialog shown, I am able to select the text control.

Comment: Updating your sample to be runnable may help you get an answer.

Comment: @RobinDunn I'll work on that, thanks. It's a bit of a pain, but hopefully worth the effort.